# How to hide sub project templates in visual studio?

Tags: vsix, project-template

I created multiple project template and rename .vstemplate files. And I created VSIX extensions.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNgiY.png)

But I want to show only multiple project template. How can I hide other sub templates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your sub templates hidden, by setting the Hidden element in your sub template's .vstemplate to true. See the following doc topic for reference:

[Hidden Element (Visual Studio templates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/hidden-element-visual-studio-templates)